# Question about interfaces and pointer receiver in Go

Tags: go, interface

I everyone,

I wonder about the significant differences between interfaces and pointer receiver, because both do the same thing.

Can you tell me what the difference between this 2 code snippet:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p *Person) IncreaseAge(age int) *Person {
    p.Age = age
    return p
}

player1 := &Person{Age: 25,}
player1.IncreaseAge(55)
```

and this one with interface

```
type Increaser interface { IncreaseAge(age int) Person }

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p *Person) IncreaseAge(age int) *Person {
    p.Age = age
    return p
}
var player2 Increaser
player2 = &Person {Age: 25,}
player2.IncreaseAge(55)
```

I don't understand the benefits of interfaces in this case. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "Difference" doesn't mean here actually. You are talking about 2 separate things. We can `player2.IncreaseAge(55)` because you defined `IncreaseAge()` as a method for `Person`, and in the second snippet, you are just storing your `&Person {Age: 25,}` into an interface variable, and you can assign anything into it that implemented the `IncreaseAge()` method.

Comment: There is no benefit to having an interface here, as there is also no reason to use an interface. If there is no reason, don't use one.

Comment: I know there is no benefits of interface heure. The things is that i don't well understand interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces only make sense when there are multiple different types that have **some common behavior** (well defined as a set of function signatures) but different implementation of that behavior and you want to pass those different types as argument into a single function that can **based on this common behavior** defined by the interface (and maybe some external inputs) do something no matter what concrete type was passed to it (as long as that type implements given interface).

Let's say you want to add type `Dog` and method `Introduce()` to both `Person` and `Dog` that will return introduction message. In case of `Person` method `Introduce()` should return introduction with name and age of that particular person, in case of `Dog` just `bark bark` as dogs can't speak human tongue. Now somewhere in code you want to have single function `SayHi(x)` which will no matter if `x` is `Person` or `Dog` print output of `Introduce()` (they both have that "behavior"). That would be valid interface use case:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type Dog struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p Person) Introduce() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("I'm a person named %s and %d years old", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func (d Dog) Introduce() string {
    // Dogs cannot talk to human so they just bark to introduce themselves
    return fmt.Sprintf("bark bark!")
}

type Introducer interface {
    Introduce() string
}

func SayHi(i Introducer) {
    fmt.Println(i.Introduce())
}

func main() {
    p := Person{"Timmy", 7}
    d := Dog{"Lassie", 5}

    // Here you can use SayHi no matter if it is Person or Dog...
    SayHi(p)
    SayHi(d)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wjHgPu7Esvr

One of good examples of interface is [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) from standard library. Which describes behavior of being able to read bytes (having a method `Read(p []byte) (int, error)`). There are [many different implementations](https://golang.org/search?q=Read#Global) of this interface that can read from file, network connection, archive, cipher, etc. Thanks to existence of `io.Reader` you can write a function that doesn't care from where the bytes come.

If you don't have need to do this, obviously you don't need to create interface. Overdoing interfaces where they aren't needed leads to cluttered code. Ideally start without them and if you find yourself in position where you spot commonality or in need of common behavior in multiple types refactor the code and create interface.

Comment: I don't understand your example, because both of person and dog are declared as struct and not interface.. and your sayHi fonction accept an introducer interface as argument ?!

Comment: @user1310969 That's the entire point of interface. Instead of concrete type you use interface (in the exchange you can only use methods specified by that interface) and then any type that implements those methods (implements the interface) can be passed. So my interface is `Introducer` and both `Person` and `Dog` implement that interface so I need only one `SayHi()`.